# Embed a PlaceAutocompleteFragment in a RecyclerView

Tags: java, android

How can I use `PlaceAutoCompleteFragment` in RecyclerView. Plus which is the best practice to apply place autocomplete. According to the documentation.

There are two options for adding the autocomplete widget to your app:

Option 1: Embed a `PlaceAutocompleteFragment`.

Option 2: Use an intent to launch the autocomplete activity.

I am quite confused since this is the first time I am trying to use it.